# Show the floating images as same height

Tags: html, css

Please check the code at http://jsfiddle.net/jfzZQ/

We are displaying two floating images dynamically next to each other. We are setting up the width of the images to 200px and not setting the height parameter.

As the images are of different proportions, the height of one image is longer than the other.

```
<style>
 .img200 {width:200px;}
 .credit {position: absolute; bottom: 8px; left: 8px; 
 width: 100%; color: #fff;font-size: 11px;}
</style>
<div style="width:405px;">
<div style="position: relative; float:left;">
    <img class="img200" src="http://images.theage.com.au/2012/12/19/3902461/art-353-        svMESSI-300x0.jpg" /> <span class="credit">site 1</span>

</div>
<div style="position: relative; float:right;">
    <img class="img200" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2012/12/04/article-2242647-11D1474C000005DC-964_634x664.jpg" /> <span class="credit">site 2</span>

</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">new line here</div>
<br />
<br />
<div style="width:405px;">
 <div style="position: relative; float:left;">
    <img class="img200" src="http://nimg.sulekha.com/sports/original700/lionel-messi-2009-12-21-15-41-46.jpg" /> <span class="credit">site 1</span>

</div>
<div style="position: relative; float:right;">
    <img class="img200" src="http://media.npr.org/assets/img/2013/06/12/messi122way_custom-74f98cf7a4148d6405ad71c75457f7a4f516a9c9-s6-c30.jpg" /> <span class="credit">site 2</span>

</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">new line here</div>
```

Is it possible to hide bottom part of one of the images, so that they both show as same height. In case 1, we would like to hide bottom part of the left image and in case 2 we would like to hide bottom part of right image.

Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: You can use JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jfzZQ/4/

Answer (score 2):

1)

Create 2 divs of equal height and set the images as their background

---

2)

Change of tactic .. background works but your images are too big. Lets overflow instead by adding this to the divs:

```
height: 200px; overflow: hidden;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jfzZQ/1/

Notice i'm not fixing the height/width of the image. Only the width of the image is set as to keep the height/width proportions automatic. I'm just setting the height of the div and cutting it off with overflow.

3)

The solution from Mohammad seems fine to me

Did some css refactoring ..so don't know if you like it. If you prefer solution 3, be sure to give the creds to Mohammad & not me

http://jsfiddle.net/jfzZQ/5/

Comment: Robert: we can't set the css height parameter, as the height needs to be dynamic. As you see in 2nd case, your code is applying the overflow:hidden to both the images and they ended up looking square.

Comment: Then set it to 300px to make it look rectangular :) The proportions will be respected (the height is dynamic in proportion to the width) ..just the bottom is cut off at a given measure, but you have to choose a size.. You can either use this pure css solution, or you will have to resort to some awful calculations to see which is higher, choose which you want shorter and apply js to readjust all that.

Comment: You don't need JS for this simple task. setting the width to auto and height to a specific value with work just fine.

Comment: none of the solutios work Robert. The basic requirement got changed with your solutions. We need the images to take 400px width in total and the height needs to change dynamically based on the proportion.

Comment: If neither http://jsfiddle.net/jfzZQ/1/ (hides the bottom part) nor http://jsfiddle.net/jfzZQ/5/ (makes them the same height) do what you want i think we misunderstood your question

Comment: image 1 width + image 2 width should be 400px. But with jsfiddle.net/jfzZQ/5 the criteria is failing. Thanks.

Comment: That's what http://jsfiddle.net/jfzZQ/1/ does. And yes the bottom is cut off, not squished

Comment: Can you please explain where http://jsfiddle.net/jfzZQ/1/ doesn't fit the request ? Quote: "We are setting up the width of the images to 200px and not setting the height parameter. As the images are of different proportions, the height of one image is longer than the other. Is it possible to hide bottom part of one of the images, so that they both show as same height."

Comment: Are you kidding me because you didn't want it square and i said you could just make the height bigger if you wanted to, and somehow you didn't understand how to do that ? Easy: http://jsfiddle.net/jfzZQ/6/

Comment: Hi Robert, jsfiddle.net/jfzZQ/6 is of no good too. the reasons are in case 1, the 2nd image got stretched vertically (proportions got changed) and in case 2, both the images bottom parts got trimmed.

Comment: Ok forget it.. In solutions 1, 2, 3 images where not stretched. In jsfiddle.net/jfzZQ/6 image is streched (if needed) to fill any missing space, but in "none" of the examples are proportions changed.

Comment: Sorry Robert, you tried to help, but none of the solutions are complete, each one leads to a newer issue. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set both pictures' width to `auto`, and their height to a specific value.

```
img {
   width:auto;
   height: /* make height same for both*/
}
```

That way, it will keep the proportions of both images and it will also make them smaller or bigger depending on the height. Make sure you don't add too much height, though, or the images will go to the next line.

Comment: one image is 300px × 469px, the other 634px × 664px ..that's gonna look quirky. Right now the width is fixed and the height is auto, your solution will just invert the problem

Comment: lol, if i helped you why don't you go ahead and accept and question and/or upvote, Thanks